# Create a variable in a sproc based on definition of a column in a table

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to use a column's definition in a table to define a variable in a sproc?  For example in table Employees, there's a column called LastName.  In INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, you can obtain the DATA_TYPE ('nvarchar') and the CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH (50).  I would like to know if it's possible to use these two descriptors in order to create a variable in a sproc.  I saw a technique someone used in Oracle that was very similar.  They created a table and used the definition to declare a variable:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_CONSTANTS (
    MAX_LEN VARCHAR2(32)
);


DECLARE x TEST_CONSTANTS.MAX_LEN%TYPE;
BEGIN
    x := 'Test';
    dbms_output.put_line(x);
END;
```

I'm looking to do something similar to this.  That way if the column in the table changes, I may not have to change my code (also I'd rather not use varchar(max) either).

Let me know if any further clarification is needed.

TIA!!

Comment: You would need dynamic SQL to do what you want

Comment: T-SQL isn't really a language that goes in for meta-programming. Is your entire purpose just to declare a variable of a funny type, or do you have an actual problem to solve?

Comment: Actually, just realised that you've tagged SQL-Server, but your code doesn't appear to be T-SQL. Have you tagged wrongly? Maybe you're aiming for Oracle?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Apparently he wants to do something similar in SQL Server to what that Oracle code is doing

Comment: The code I included was sample code I found in a Oracle blog.  I was hoping to use it as a sort of "data dictionary".  Define it in a table and then whenever you have to create a variable matching the column, you can do it "dynamically".  If the column changes (generally only length), you don't have to search all your code to make sure the variables got changed as well.

Comment: Sounds like dynamic sql is what you are looking for. If you don't require that the local variable matches the field exactly, you could always use varchar(max) and then you are prepared for the length of the field in the table to grow.

Comment: You can use SQL_VARIANT, VARCHAR(MAX), or other oversized types to do this, as well as dynamic SQL. Generally though, you're going to just need to use the right type in code, and if the column changes to be larger than the variables you were putting it in, then you'll have to update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no TSQL syntax to define a variable's datatype based on a column's type.

In principle you can use user defined datatypes to do something similar to this,

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[EmployeeLastName] 
FROM [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL;

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
  (
     EmployeeId INT PRIMARY KEY,
     LastName   [dbo].[EmployeeLastName]  NOT NULL
  )

DECLARE @X [dbo].[EmployeeLastName] 

SET @X = 'Test'
```

But in practice they have various limitations which will probably put you off the idea. See Bart Duncan's article [T-SQL UDTs. (Huh!) What are they good for?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2010/08/25/t-sql-udts-what-are-they-good-for.aspx) for some of these.